# Any difference between a consistent set of sentences and a consistent set of formulas?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In several model theory textbooks consistency is only defined for a set of sentences and never for a set of formulas. However, when I researched on-line, there didn't seem to be any problems transferring the exact same definition and theory/theorems from sets of sentences to sets of formulas? Are there any traps for sets of formulas that I am not seeing?

This is within first order logic.

Comment: Any traps? Not really, as long as you're clear about your treatment of free variables. A convention I'm familiar with treats formulas with free variables as implicitly closed with universal quantifiers. However, conventions vary: I can't cite an example, but I think some authors treat such formulas as *existentially* closed, which is a different notion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The potential trap is that not everybody agrees about how to treat free variables: if I am thinking about satisfiability I find it natural to treat them as existentially quantified and if I am thinking about consistency (or whether a formula has a model) I would find it natural to treat them as universally quantified. However, there is no general agreement about this. Sticking with sentences saves having to worry about this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the truth value of a sentence does not depend on the assignment of variables.

For example, $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$ are both true in $\Bbb R$ with the usual order if the assignment gives both $x$ and $y$ the same value, but a not in general.